# If all is OK echo ok but if one of all is not echo not ok

Tags: php, logic

for example I will write
$data = [ok,ok,ok,ok,ok]
I would like to echo "ok"

but if
$data = [ok,ok,ok,not,ok]
I would like to echo "not ok"

I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Count if all values are 'ok'.

```
$data = ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok'];
echo count(array_filter($data, fn($v) => $v !== 'ok')) ? 'not ok' : 'ok', PHP_EOL;

$data = ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'not', 'ok'];
echo count(array_filter($data, fn($v) => $v !== 'ok')) ? 'not ok' : 'ok', PHP_EOL;
```

echoes

```
ok
not ok
```